# Aria download links are down?Any other way to install ROSARIA?

Tags: ros, rosaria, ros-indigo, aria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I ve been following http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA in order to install ROSARIA in my 64bits Ubuntu trusty. However, step 0.1 asks to install Aria and the links seem to be down, I have been searching other ways to download them with no success so I got stuck, I dont know if it is a temporary failure of their servers in which case I ll delete the post.
Any help is welcome :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290218/aria-download-links-are-down?any-other-way-to-install-rosaria?/) by [chokapik](https://answers.ros.org/users/34926/chokapik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could of course be a transient issue, and I don't know whether things have already progressed so much that the site is taken down, but Reed Hedges (former Omron/Adept employee) posted to `ros-sig-pioneer` some time ago: [Future of rosaria and Aria](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-pioneer/PnJS6FPwAU4):

> Hello,
>
> As many of you know, MobileRobots LLC is now shut down and Omron/Adept is no longer maintaining or supporting ARIA, or manufacturing research robots (Pioneer etc.).
>
> I no longer work for Omron/Adept.
>
> ARIA and other software and documentation is still available from http://robots.mobilerobots.com, but I don't know how long Omron/Adept plans to keep that website online.
>
> If rosaria users, or ARIA users in general, are interested in creating a fork of ARIA that can continue to be used with rosaria, and developed or updated itself, I may be able to help a little bit.   This would also be an opportunity to make changes to ARIA that were previously not possible in the official/upstream ARIA due to constraints from internal use by ARIA at Adept or other compatibility requirements.  I would also suggest a minor change to the name.
>
> The first step would probably be to get the last GPL release of ARIA source and put it on github, and perhaps start with some simplifications and updates (I've been looking at this already.)
>
> The alternatives to users of Pioneer robots and ROS is to switch to the "p2os" ROS driver, or to just drop a copy of ARIA source code into rosaria in a "frozen" state and continue using it as-is with no future changes for as long as possible.
>
> I can also continue to try to answer questions and provide information about ARIA and Pioneer robots here or elsewhere, though I no longer have the same amount of time or resources for in depth testing or debugging.
>
> What would you like to do?
>
> Reed

I don't know whether any conclusion was reached, but it seems like there are plans to host the (already GPL-ed) code on github.

Perhaps reaching out to that community if/when you keep having issues with downloading it would be a good first step?

---

The Internet Archive seems to have a large part of the mobilerobots site archived: [archive.org/http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Main_Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180205215712/http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Main_Page).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chokapik](https://answers.ros.org/users/34926/chokapik/) on 2018-05-02**:
Working perfectly thanks to you @gvdhoorn, I found both Aria and MobileSim in the Internet Archive.

I also came across a project on github https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/libaria but the *.deb installation is just simpler.